# PyTorch tensor.sum() performance drops with large tensors vs. NumPy

Tags: python, performance, pytorch

`tensor.sum()` performance drops once my tensor exceeds a certain size. Why is that?

```
import torch

tensor = torch.FloatTensor(200_000, 2_000).uniform_() > 0.8 # random 1's and 0's
tensor[:, :1000].sum(dim=0)
tensor[:, :2000].sum(dim=0) # 2x wider but 20x slower
```

Profiling:

```
import time
import torch

start = time.time()
tensor[:, :1000].sum(dim=0)
end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 0.69s

start = time.time()
tensor[:, :2000].sum(dim=0)
end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 20s
```

NumPy doesn't appear to share this limitation:

```
import numpy as np

start = time.time()
np.array(tensor[:, :2000]).sum(axis=0)
end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 0.40s
```

Comment: Unable to replicate. On my machine, `_ = tensor[:, :1000].sum(dim=0)` takes 184 ms and `_ = tensor[:, :2000].sum(dim=0)` takes 327 ms.

Comment: I can replicate this in a fresh conda environment on my 2020 M1 8 GB MacBook Air

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce, same as Karl. Also increased the size to check for some RAM/bandiwdth issue. Still, found nothing wrong:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from time import time


tensor = torch.FloatTensor(200_000, 16_000).uniform_() > 0.8 # random 1's and 0's

all_timings = []
all_sizes = np.arange(1600, 16001, 1600)
for size in all_sizes:
    timings = []
    for _ in range(5):
        start_time = time()
        tensor[:, :size].sum(dim=0)
        timings.append(time() - start_time)

    all_timings.append(min(timings))

plt.plot(all_sizes, all_timings)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Timings are increasing linearly, as expected.